# A rectangle is twice as long as it is wide.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

A Farmer fenced a rectangular area with $75$ metres of chicken wire.
The rectangle is twice as long as it is wide.
What are its dimensions?

Comment: 12.5m x 25m - draw a picture and try yourself

Comment: Welcome to Math.StackExchange! Please show us what you have tried, so that we can help you. This site is not a "do my homework" site, you need to show that you have genuinely tried your hand at it.

Comment: I concur with Jack .... definitely, draw a picture.

Answer (score 2):

A rectangle has two sets of equal sides. Denote those opposite sides by, say, $x$ and $y$, respectively. Thus the perimeter is given by $2x+2y = 75$ which implies $x+y = 37.5$. Next, we have one of the sides is twice as long as the other, giving us a second equation: $x = 2y$. Solving these two equations simultaneously gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$2(l+b)=75$$
where $l=2b$

giving you $b=12.5 m$ and $l=25m$

Kindly go through basics of pariimeters and areas again @OP. Sincere advice